# Apply surrounding html elements on queried map

Tags: json, xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am querying a map to build some elements that should be wrapped in elements html, head and body.

I just added the key 'run' because I do not know how to call the 3rd template without matching something in the map. The both "store" templates produces expected result if they are run individual or both, but when attempting to wrap then inside the body element, (using the 3rd template) it fails.

Since I am planning to modularize the XSLT and templates I am not looking to reduced amount of template, unless necessary.

**JSON:**

```
<data>
{

  "run": "",
  
  "store-1": {
    "pencils": 4,
    "rulers": 1
  },
  "store-2": {
    "milk": 2,
    "water": 5
  }
}
</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/1"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="base">
    <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">office</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <!-- Block all data that has no user defined template -->
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Build elements in store [1] -->

  <xsl:template name="items-store-1" match="*[@key = 'store-1']//*[@key and not(*)]">

    <xsl:element
      name="item:{@key}"
      use-attribute-sets="base"
      >{.}</xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Build elements in store [2] -->

  <xsl:template name="items-store-2" match="*[@key = 'store-2']//*[@key and not(*)]">

    <xsl:element
      name="item:{@key}"
      use-attribute-sets="base"
      >{.}</xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Build surrounding elements -->

  <xsl:template match="*[@key='run']">

    <head><title>MyTitle</title></head>

  <body>
    <store-1>
      <xsl:call-template name="items-store-1"/>
    </store-1>
    <store-2>
      <xsl:call-template name="items-store-2"/>
    </store-2>
  </body>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/1">
   <head>
      <title>MyTitle</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <store-1>
         <item:run contextRef="office"/>
      </store-1>
      <store-2>
         <item:run contextRef="office"/>
      </store-2>
   </body>
   <item:pencils contextRef="office">4</item:pencils>
   <item:rulers contextRef="office">1</item:rulers>
   <item:milk contextRef="office">2</item:milk>
   <item:water contextRef="office">5</item:water>
</html>
```

**Wanted Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/1">
   <head>
      <title>MyTitle</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <store-1>
       <item:pencils contextRef="office">4</item:pencils>
       <item:rulers contextRef="office">1</item:rulers>
      </store-1>
      <store-2>
       <item:milk contextRef="office">2</item:milk>
       <item:water contextRef="office">5</item:water>
      </store-2>
   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would output the `head` and `body` in the first template where you create the `html` anyway and then it seems adding second template suffices to use the other ones you have:

```
  <xsl:template match="data">
    <html>
      <head><title>MyTitle</title></head>

      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*:map[starts-with(@key, 'store')]">
      <xsl:element name="{@key}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Asn an alternative, the "root" container of your XML converted JSON is a key-less map thus if you want to match on it you can use

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:item="http://www.example.org/1"
  expand-text="yes"
>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:attribute-set name="base">
    <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">office</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <!-- Block all data that has no user defined template -->
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*:map[starts-with(@key, 'store')]">
      <xsl:element name="{@key}">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Build elements in store [1] -->

  <xsl:template name="items-store-1" match="*[@key = 'store-1']//*[@key and not(*)]">

    <xsl:element
      name="item:{@key}"
      use-attribute-sets="base"
      >{.}</xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Build elements in store [2] -->

  <xsl:template name="items-store-2" match="*[@key = 'store-2']//*[@key and not(*)]">

    <xsl:element
      name="item:{@key}"
      use-attribute-sets="base"
      >{.}</xsl:element>

  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*:map[not(@key)]">
    <head><title>MyTitle</title></head>
    <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```